# Covert binary 64-bit timestamp offset from the GPS epoch to python datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, binary

I'm trying to figure out what I think should be an 8byte/64-bit timestamp.

```
import datetime
GPS_EPOCH = datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 6)
t1 = "\x00\x00\xBF\x13\xDB\x79\xC0\x00" # expected: 2012-10-04 01:00:51.759
t2 = "\x00\x00\xC0\x13\xDB\x79\xC0\x00" # expected: 2012-10-04 01:00:51.760
t3 = "\x00\x00\xC2\x13\xDB\x79\xC0\x00" # expected: 2012-10-04 01:00:51.763
t4 = "\x00\x00\x80\xE7\xFB\x79\xC0\x00" # expected: 2012-10-04 01:45:40.960
```

I believe the value(s?) resulting from `t1` and `t2` should be offset from the GPS_EPOCH.
However, I can't seem to get the result to match the expected result datetime.

I've been reading up and it seems logical that this would be split into 2 parts, with one perhaps being fractional and the other seconds (4 bytes each?).  However, I haven't found any reference for timestamp formats that are based off the GPS epoch.

Any ideas how this could be transformed into the expected result?

Comment: please, post a list of different strings and expected values to look for some pattern.

Comment: Your third example is incorrect. And we need samples that are more than a day apart.

Comment: Thanks, I've added another sample.  I don't have a sample time from another date at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have it. You provided just enough examples.

```
>>> t1 = b"\x00\x00\xBF\x13\xDB\x79\xC0\x00" # expected: 2012-10-04 01:00:51.759
>>> import struct
>>> import datetime
>>> GPS_EPOCH = datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 6)
>>> t1_unpacked = struct.unpack('<q', t1)[0]
>>> t1_seconds = t1_unpacked // 52428800
>>> t1_us = int(round((t1_unpacked % 52428800) / 52.428800, 0))
>>> GPS_EPOCH + datetime.timedelta(seconds=t1_seconds, microseconds=t1_us)
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 4, 1, 0, 51, 758750)
```

Putting it all together:

```
def gps_time(timestamp):
    unpacked = struct.unpack('<q', timestamp)[0]
    seconds = unpacked // 52428800
    microseconds = int(round((unpacked % 52428800) / 52.428800, 0))
    return GPS_EPOCH + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds, microseconds=microseconds)

>>> gps_time(t2)
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 4, 1, 0, 51, 760000)
>>> gps_time(t3)
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 4, 1, 0, 51, 762500)
>>> gps_time(t4)
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 4, 1, 45, 40, 960000)
```

Comment: @monkut, I deduced this from the information you provided. My Google skills didn't turn up anything.

Comment: waw! nice job +1. This is the kind of high level answer with low upvote, its a pity. Someone else write a simple SQL sentence and gets 6 votes. Congratulations, you are the man!

Answer (score 2):

You can see if your eight bytes encodes a 64-bit integer by using the standard library's [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/struct.html) module:

```
>>> import struct
>>> number = struct.unpack('q', "\x00\x00\xBF\x13\xDB\x79\xC0\x00")
>>> "{:,}".format(number)
'54,177,177,364,529,152'
```

That's a pretty big integer!  But is it related to the epoch you list?  Probably not...

Maybe it's not an integer.  I've got a raw GPS module I've been playing with and its data comes out as serial in NMEA sentences.  You can find [format information for those](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/) online.

Comment: I have taken unpack method from you +1 in my edited answer. If this is a problem for you I can delete my answer. Also, I'm the first people to see your profile ;)

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

Sorry, **this is not a solution**, only some **start point** if someone else has more time to touch in depth.

The stored 'hidden' number for first date should be:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
GPS_EPOCH = datetime(1980, 1, 6)
date_1 = datetime(2012,10,04, 01,00,51,759)
d=(date_1 - GPS_EPOCH)
( d.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + d.seconds ) * 1000 + d.microseconds

---->   1.033.347.651.759   <----
```

But the number you get unpacking first data hex code is:

```
struct.unpack('q', "\xBF\x13\xDB\x79\xC0\x00\x00\x00" )[0]

---->     826.678.121.407   <----
```

Notice that I move \xBF to least significant digit position. I do this because in your sample 1 millisecond is \xC0 - \xBF. The least significant digit seems to be \xBF in first sample.

Then, for your data sample, the formula can be:

```
 milliseconds =  ( 1033347651759 - 826678121407 ) +  unpack_your_string_with_offset
 GPS_EPOCH + milliseconds
```

Testing with your less data ...

```
>>> milliseconds =  ( 1033347651759 - 826678121407 ) + \ 
                    struct.unpack('q', "\xBF\x13\xDB\x79\xC0\x00\x00\x00" )[0]
>>> 
>>> GPS_EPOCH + timedelta( milliseconds = milliseconds)
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 4, 1, 0, 51, 759000)
```

Please, **post more data samples** and expected results to check or infer a new formula.

**I have taken unpack method from @leon_matthews: +1 ;)**

I hope some [Raiman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095953/) guy can found the solution. I will follow your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!  It seems that you're getting the known milliseconds from the "expected" datetime and then adding and subtracting the unpacked value.  Unfortunately, this doesn't help yet, as it results in only adding the "expected" datetime offset to the gps epoch.