# Python : hex to date time

Tags: python, datetime, gps, hex

```
23 DD 78 34 = 2013-01-28 21:52:XX //second not sure
92 e3 78 34 = 2013-01-28 22:14:XX 
d4 e3 78 34 = 2013-01-28 22:15:XX 
16 e4 78 34 = 2013-01-28 22:16:XX
```

how to convert hex to date time?it is not UNIX Date

Comment: How is you hex value specified?

Comment: @ber i have no idea,maybe is endian-swapped?

Comment: Do you have more examples of hex values and their corresponding time stamps?

Comment: What mtrw said, and also... where are you getting these Hex values?   That might give a hint on what the epoch is (epoch for Unix time is 1970; some other system might use a different epoch)

Comment: @Foon, those data i get it from a GPS device, and i don't know the epoch.

Comment: If a=0x3478dd23 and b=0x3478e416, then b-a=1779. However, there are 24 to 25 minutes between your first and last date. It doesn't seem obvious how to fit these 24 minutes in 1779 "units of something"... For example, if it's 1779 seconds, it's a bit too much since 25*60=1500

Comment: @arbautjc the minutes maybe having some gap, when the device are sending the data to server are delay,not 100% are 24mins,maybe 25mins or 26mins,because the datetime is the server received the data, so the datetime are nearby with the hex string

Comment: @Anthor Yes, but it wouldn't work anyway. Try x=479070157 Now, in python, time.ctime(0x3478dd23+x) = 'Mon Jan 28 21:52:00 2013'.
But time.ctime(0x3478e416+x) = 'Mon Jan 28 22:21:39 2013', which seems much too late. Also, GPS epoch should be january 1980 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29), but
time.ctime(x) = 'Thu Mar  7 20:02:37 1985'

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814588/covert-binary-64-bit-timestamp-offset-from-the-gps-epoch-to-python-datetime-obje

Comment: @Mark With the function given in this page,
gps_time("\x00\x00\x00\x30\x57\x5b\xC2\x00") = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 28, 21, 52)
It does not look like data given by Anthor.
We may need more information on the GPS device involved...

Comment: @Anthor, please add another example if you get the chance. The epoch and tick timing appear to be nonstandard and it's important to get a larger time range to calculate an accurate figure. And can you tell us exactly which GPS device you're using?

Answer (score 1):

The hex value looks like it is little endian encoded, but it does not seam to use seconds as tick values:

```
>>> values = [
...    (0x3478dd23, datetime(2013, 1, 28, 21, 52)),
...    (0x3478e392, datetime(2013, 1, 28, 22, 14)),
...    (0x3478e3d4, datetime(2013, 1, 28, 22, 15)),
...    (0x3478e416, datetime(2013, 1, 28, 22, 16))
... ]
...
>>> for s, dt in values:
...     print dt - datetime.fromtimestamp(s)
... 
5544 days, 19:02:37
5544 days, 18:57:10
5544 days, 18:57:04
5544 days, 18:56:58
```

Since the offset is shrinking over time I calculated a correction factor:

```
>>> ts_delta = values[1][0] - values[0][0]
>>> ts_delta
1647
>>> dt_delta = values[1][1] - values[0][1]
>>> dt_delta
datetime.timedelta(0, 1320)
>>> dt_delta = dt_delta.days * 60*60*24 + dt_delta.seconds
>>> dt_delta
1320
>>> factor = float(dt_delta) / float(ts_delta)
>>> factor
0.8014571948998178
```

1647 ticks = 1320 seconds.

Now if we apply this factor to the timestamps the offset stays pretty much constant (except for the seconds but since you didn't know their value I had just used 0 in the source data)

```
>>> for s, dt in values:
...     print dt - datetime.fromtimestamp(s * factor)
... 
7567 days, 17:16:08.233151
7567 days, 17:16:08.233151
7567 days, 17:16:15.336976
7567 days, 17:16:22.440802
```

Taking this into account you can use this offset and factor to convert the original values:

```
>>> offset = values[0][1] - datetime.fromtimestamp(values[0][0]*factor)
>>> offset
datetime.timedelta(7567, 62168, 233151)

def hex_to_datetime(s):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(s*factor) + offset

>>> for s, dt in values:
...     print hex_to_datetime(s), dt
... 
2013-01-28 21:52:00 2013-01-28 21:52:00
2013-01-28 22:14:00 2013-01-28 22:14:00
2013-01-28 22:14:52.896175 2013-01-28 22:15:00
2013-01-28 22:15:45.792349 2013-01-28 22:16:00
```

This looks quite promising to me.

Answer (score 1):

So, the hex integers are obviously little-endian. To converting to integers:

```
880336163 > 2013-01-28 21:52:XX
880337810 > 2013-01-28 22:14:XX
880337876 > 2013-01-28 22:15:XX
880337942 > 2013-01-28 22:16:XX
```

And considering the delta between the last three, the value is in seconds.

Using the date provided and working back the corresponding numbers of seconds, you get the following epoch dates:

```
1985-03-07 20:02:37
1985-03-07 19:57:10
1985-03-07 19:57:04
1985-03-07 19:56:58
```

Even allowing for time skewing and sampling errors, the epoch looks odd. GPS epoch is January 6, 1980 I think... You'll need more samples to determine an accurate epoch.

Anyway, here's the script I used to derive the epochs:

```
import datetime as dt                                                           

data = [                                                                        
    ('23 DD 78 34',(2013,01,28,21,52)),                                         
    ('92 e3 78 34',(2013,01,28,22,14)),                                         
    ('d4 e3 78 34',(2013,01,28,22,15)),                                         
    ('16 e4 78 34',(2013,01,28,22,16)),
    ]

def hex_to_int(string):
    string = ''.join(reversed(string.split()))
    return int(string,16)

for (string,date) in data:
    secs = hex_to_int(string)
    date = dt.datetime(*date)
    delta = dt.timedelta(seconds=secs)
    print date - delta
```

Once you have the epoch, convert the hex string to an integer as above and add it to the epoch to get the corresponding date time:

```
import datetime as dt
epoch = dt.datetime(YYYY,MM,DD,HH,MM,SS)
def hex_to_datetime(string):
    delta = dt.timedelta(seconds=hex_to_int(string))
    return epoch + delta
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's more likely that the value isn't in exact 1.0 second intervals than the epoch changes.